# How can I know the number of the active DDP session in my meteor app?

Tags: meteor, ddp

In a Meteor App, how can I know the number of the active DDP sessions and get some information for them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the `Meteor.server.sessions` object on the server.  The `connectionHandle` sub-object is probably the most useful property of each.  I've only played around with these rather than using them for anything meaningful, but it seems to do what you require.